# Microsoft Bing Speecg Api in Windows Form C#

Tags: bing, speech

Hi I am trying to use my Microsoft Bing Speech Api in my C# windows form Project. But i cannot find any examples in C# Windows form project and all the examples are available only in the WPF.

Help me how to use Microsoft Bing Speech Api in C# Windows Project

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [new speech service SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/) support C# .NET 4.6.1 on Windows. Is this something you are looking for?